# How to Post Data to the Same Page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically all I am trying to do is send the form data to the same location of the form.

The code should:

1. Get the #submit click action
2. Extract #email, #selection1, and #selection2's data
3. Hide the form #form
4. Display #email, #selection1, and #selection2 inside paragraph #preview

I have no JQuery experience so I am lost. I tried looking around and trying different codes but nothing would work for me.

My form code is:

```
<form method="post" id="form">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <select class="form-control" id="selection1">
                        <option>Option 1</option>
                        <option>Option 2</option>
                     </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <select class="form-control" id="selection2">
                        <option selected="selected">Option 1</option>
                        <option>Option 2</option>
                        <option>Option 3</option>
                        <option>Option 4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
                    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign in</button>
                </div>
</form>

<p id="preview"></p>
```

Here is the JQUery I tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#submit").click(function () {
          var FormVal = {
              datafield1: $('#email').val(),
              datafield2: $('#field2').val()
          };

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              data: FormVal,
              async: false,
              success: function (response) {
                  $('#preview').html($('#email').val() + '<br />' + $('#selection1').val()) + '<br />' + $('#selection2').val());
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to go through all those AJAX stuffs to accomplish what you need. You can simply hide the form and then set the value to the paragraph `#preview`

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
  //get value like this..
  var datafield1 = $("#email").val();
  //hiding the form
  $("#form").hide(function () {
    //setting the text to #preview
    $('#preview').html(
    $('#email').val() + '<br />' + $('#selection1').val() + '<br />' + $('#selection2').val());
  });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/F2usu/) of the working code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#preview').html($('#email').val() + '<br />' + $('#selection1').val()) + '<br />' + $('#selection2').val());
```

You have an extra parentheses in this code here: `$('#selection1').val())`. You can use the console of your browser to debug syntax errors.